# Alternative to CXF WSPasswordCallback

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

For the SOAP client I'm implementing the signing of the certificate by using CXF security.

In all provided samples the reference to the passwordCallback class is set in WSS4JOutInterceptor properties.

```
 securityProperties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, UTPasswordCallback.class.getName());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(securityProperties));
```

Is there an alternative approach to the WSPasswordCallback? Can I set the password directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution by setting the password in requestContext:

```
client.getRequestContext().put("password", "PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the private key password for the keystore in the Crypto properties file as well you are using for signature: http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html

Comment: if you mean org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password, then I have it already but it's not enough. Without passwordCallback I get "WSHandler: application provided null or empty password"

Comment: No, I meant org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password

Comment: This property doesn't solve the problem. Still have the same exception